# How to change regular price of Woocommerce Product using hook?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

woocommerce hook for changing regular price is not giving results as expected it is not changing the price of product.

I am trying to change regular price of Woocommerce products using filter hook "woocommerce_product_get_regular_price".It is working fine for the products that have regular and sale price(it changes regular price).But for the products that only have regular price it won't change the price of that product.

I am trying only for simple product and testing it for simple product only.